# awesomewm: a function to move all open clients to their designated screens/tags

Tags: function, lua, awesome-wm

Reading on the use of mod + x: run lua code I wanted to insert a function in my rc.lua that would move all opened clients (back) to their screens and tags. Everytime I take my laptop out of the docking the windows end up on one screen on the first tag, so If I could restore them running a function, that would save me a lot of time.

But...
I have no experience in LUA at all, so I tried this

```
shuffle = function(...)
    clientlist = {}
    for i, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
        -- assign tag
        -- c:tags (tag)
        -- c:move_to_screen ([s=c.screen.index+1])
        table.insert(clientlist,c.name)
        naughty.notify{c.name}    
    end
    naughty.notify{table.concat(clientlist,'\n')}
end
```

When I run this, I get a number of notifications, that respond to the number of open clients + 1, but there is nothing in them.
What am I doing wrong ?

Also, is there an easier way to debug this, instead of using the notify box ?

Comment: What do you mean with "designated screen/tags"? Do you just want to apply the `awful.rules`-rules again to everything?

Comment: I didn't want to put the placement in rules, because I don't always open a class on the same screen/tag. I only need a faster way to move the clients after I return to my desk, so I can at least start working immediately again and I have an idea where clients might be. I'm using three displays and 12 named tags, but I have 7 or 8 terminal-emulators with tmux'es for specific tasks, all with their specific tags (ie. clients, internal, local, dev, lab...)

Comment: Okay, then... how should the code know what the designated screen/tag is?

Comment: @UliSchlachter I just hardcode it in an array, much like it is done in the 'rules'-section

Comment: In that case you already know what to do, right? This question was only about the non-working notification and now everything works as you want?

Comment: @UliSchlachter yes, it was, that's why accepted your answer, although I'm still not there. Now I'm using the rules instead which is throwing errors when the laptop is not in his docking. So, I'm thinking of using a function for the display, which would return display 1 when the other two are missing

Comment: Hey @oneindelijk, did you ever manage to make a script that moves your clients to your designated screen/tags? I would be interested in it.

Comment: @gitaarik Yes, I did, sorry it took me so long to see your comment. I need to adjust my email notifications it seems. I'm currently on a trip, so I can't access the configuration, but I will share my config as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question that you are actually asking is: You need `naughty.notify{ title = c.name }`.